# Question for finding factors!

Tags: polynomials

First of all I am not a professional in mathematics. I study in class IX. My teacher gave me a worksheet in which I cannot understand a question related to factorisation of polynomials.

Here is the question:(You have to select only 1 option)

> Factors of    $p^2 (q-r)+q^2 (r-p)+r^2 (p-q)$ are :
>
> 1. $p-q$
> 2. $r^2-q$
> 3. $p^2$
> 4. $(p+q+r)$

I tried to factorise this polynomial, but I reached at a certain stage where I couldn't factorise it any more. After expanding I reached at this stage-

> $pq(p-q) + qr(q-r) + rp(r-p)$

But I can't understand how can I factorise this further.

Please help!

Comment: Take each one with two variables in the answers and use the fact that if $a+b$ is a factor then a solution is $a=-b$ does it make the equation zero? If not then it's not a factor. For $p^2$ use $p=0$ does the equation vanish? Then if all else fails (and no mistake on exam) then its the last one. Ps if you are trying to solve from first principles then you have to rearrange and see if you can factor out a common term, or use the remainder theorem (which I used above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to check if the polynomial will be constantly $0$ when the factor turns $0$.

For example, what would happen if $p - q = 0$? It turns out that 
$$ p^2 (q-r)+q^2 (r-p)+r^2 (p-q) = p^2 (p-r)+p^2 (r-p)+r^2 (p-p) = 0$$
So $p - q$ is a factor.

As for  $pq(p-q) + qr(q-r) + rp(r-p)$, the fact is that it equals to $-(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)$. Try break the term $pq(p-q)$ into $pq((p-r) + (r - q))$.

Answer (score 0):

To get a full factorisation, as it is divisible by $p-q$, the  simplest thing to do is to factor it out and consider the other factor as a polynomial in $r$:
\begin{align*}
p^2(q-r)+q^2(r-p)+r^2(p-q)&=p^2q-q^2p-p^2r+q^2r+r^2(p-q)\\
&=pq(p-q)+(q-p)(p+q)r+r^2(p-q)\\
&=(p-q)\bigl(pq-(p+q)r+r^2\bigr)\\
&=(p-q)(r-p)(r-q),
\end{align*}
which one may prefer to write as: $\,-(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)$.

Comment: But wait, in the third line, you have taken (p-q) common but it is (q-p) in the 2nd term....

Comment: $q-p=\color{red}{-}(p-q)$. That's why I have a $-$ sign$.